# use MemoryCache in nested functions in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, memorycache

I need to use MemoryCache (or IWebHostEnvironment ) in many functions that can be very nested.

Do I have to send the parameter injected to the razor page or controller to each of these functions to use MemoryCache in all of these nested functions?

Is there any better solution? for example like HttpAccessor

Comment: Be aware that you might need to refactor to a distributed cache model, if your application scales out horizontally.

Comment: yeah i know , i will need to use distributed cache like Redis in future , but my problem is not only about MemoryCache , is about use injected parameter in a lot of nested functions

Comment: That does not make it any clearer. Show us code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is depend how you develop your function. If you will register this function's class as a service inside startup.cs. There is no need to pass the memory cache to that function.

You could directly get the memory cache model by using DI. If you will not register the function as the service, you need to get the memory cache and pass it when using it in controller.

More details about how to use memory cache in asp.net core, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: my main problem was sending injected services to hundreds of nested functions. 
i have no problem to inject MemoryCache or IWebHostEnvironment in all of razor pages , because the number of pages is limited , when i register new class as a service it still need to inject in constructor of all pages , but if i want use these services in a lot of functions , i should pass these services as parameter to all of functions

Comment: Yes,this memory cache is injected by default if you want to use it in the function method, then you could get it. I couldn't understand you mean about i should pass these services as parameter to all of functions.

Comment: Suppose i have a ToJsonCustom() method in Product class , in this method i use this.GetFullName() , when i want read full name i should access to MemoryCache for reading current language , how can i access to memory cache in GetFullName() method ?
first i should inject memory cache to page , and pass it to ToJsonCustom and pass it to GetFullName .
can i access MemoryCache directly in GetFullName without pass parameter to these methods ?